Is there a way to add a dynamic named property in a class at runtime and have it known to typescript
I have a decorator that modifies a class and adds some methods to the class A. While using the instance these methods are not in autocomplete. I also get compiler errors since these properties are not known.
I know that decorators can't change the type of a class, it is not supported yet. And I'm not inclined towards using mixins since this code is going to be wrapped in a library and used by others. So it would be simpler if the users can use the @ notation.
Example:
function TypeChangeDecorator(constructor: any) {
  const keys = Reflect.getMetadata(SOME_KEY_SYMBOL, TypeB);
  return class extends constructor {
    private someClass: TypeA;
    
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      
      for(key in keys) {
        this[`set${key}`] = () => {} // some method
      }
    }

    someMethod() {
      // implementation here
    }
  }
}

@TypeChangeDecorator
class A {}

I know it might not be possible but I need to access methods someMethod and set${key}. Have the compiler not give me an error while accessing these and if possible have them in autocomplete.
PS: from what I have found this is not possible yet, but if anyone has some insights on this, it would be appreciated.

You don't really give any room here to get an answer other than "this is impossible, as you yourself noted". Decorators don't mutate the type of the class, so if you want to use decorators to mutate the type of the class by adding properties to it, then... you can't. What more can be said here?

@jcalz Yeah, thanks, I needed to hear that from someone else. I'll just extend the class with Record<K, V> and document whatever functionality there is.

For anyone looking for a solution and not use mixins, there is something called as the interface trick.
interface PropertiesAddedByDecorator {
  someMethod(): any;
}

interface A extends PropertiesAddedByDecorator;

@ TypeChangeDecorator
class A {}

// now when you do
const inst = new A();
inst.someMethod() // no error and autocomplete support

The part set${key}, is not possible, you can use Record<string, Function> to avoid compiler errors.
Also note the comment from jcalz, we can do declare someMethod: () => {} inside A instead of declaring interfaces.

This is independent of decorators, you're just narrowing the class manually. You could also write declare someMethod: ()=>any inside A as well.

@jcalz Thanks, didn't know that. This would be a cleaner implementation.

You can achieve something similar but you won't be able to use the decorator syntax with @:
interface Constructor<T> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function decorate<T extends Constructor<any>>(BaseClass: T) {
  class Extended extends BaseClass {
    logDetails() {
      console.log(`Details logged for ${this.name}, aged ${this.age}.`);
    }
  };
  return Extended;
}

class Person {
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}
  greet() {
    console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`);
  }
}

class Extension {
  logDetails() {
    console.log(`Details logged.`);
  }
}

const DecoratedPerson = decorate(Person);
const instance = new DecoratedPerson("john", 117);
instance.greet();
instance.logDetails();


Yes, I found this way but I needed something that would work with decorators

Not possible in TypeScript but maybe in the future

As of TypeScript 5.4, decorators still cannot mutate the type of the decorated class. The longstanding feature request microsoft/TypeScript#4881 is still open. Until and unless this is implemented, you'll have to give up or work around it (e.g., use a function that transforms a class, like a mixin).
